# Second monitor ain't detected anymore

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi, external-monitor, 20.10

my ubuntu (20.10) ain't detecting my second monitor via hdmi anymore. It worked well just two days ago.
Having HP Probook with 8th gen i7 and intel graphics.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Turn on legacy mode in BIOS

Don't know why it worked before and suddenly stopped.
Tried many solutions I found online, only this one helped.